# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when opening Apple Maps from iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I've trying to modify the code plenty of times, trying to see if any reference was dangling or invalid using Zombie references and nothing shows up. It looks like something goes wrong when initializing the MKMapItem or the MKMapItem with it.

MKMapItem without placemark opens the maps app.

This is the crashing code after playing around.

[image]

Original code :

```
MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:_location addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
[mapItem setName:_name];
[mapItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:nil];
```

Can't tell what is going on here.

Comment: Is `currentLocationMapItem` perhaps `nil`? — By the way, please do not show pictures of code. Show _code_.

Comment: Also may I ask what sense it would make to get driving directions to `{0,0}`?

Comment: This issue is either with the placemark or mapItem. Posted actual production code, crashes on last line.

Comment: "This issue is either with the placemark or mapItem" That's what _I_ said. Your job is to debug and find out which it is. Debug!

Comment: I've been trying so many things! If I go for the currentLocation it works fine but I have no idea where to look at anymore.

Comment: I'm not sure what it means to "try" things. Debugging means looking at the values of your variables and seeing what works and what doesn't.

Comment: So I've been trying to inspect every value, print them out, look at the pointers' adresses, it just doesn't make sense. I wouldn't post here if I could fix that up with casual debugging.

Comment: Sorry about that. But I don't know what "it just doesn't make sense" means. If you have more information, that's great, but then you should share it in your question. As it stands, there's nothing in the info you've given that allows us to help you.

Comment: What would help you here?